# Different Database Directory Per Database

Tags: database, postgresql-9.5

I want to set an default location per database
Example:

1. database1 - is on /var/www/html/database1
2. database2 - is on /var/www/html/database2

Locations stated are only examples I want to store it elsewhere like another partition of an Hard Drive.

Is this possible?
For PostgreSQL?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Use tablespaces:

```
create tablespace db1_space 
    owner = db1_owner 
    location = '/var/www/html/database1';
create tablespace db2_space 
    owner = db2_owner 
    location = '/var/www/html/database2';
```

Then create the databases with the appropriate tablespace:

```
create database db1 
   owner = db1_owner
   tablespace = db1_space;

create database db2
   owner = db2_owner
   tablespace = db2_space;
```

---

Unrelated, but: I would **never** put a tablespace below `/var/www`

Comment: No the /var/www is just an example ill try this :D

Comment: Im having this error could not set permissions on directory "/var/www/html/database": Operation not permitted

Comment: @KenTapdasan: [from the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/manage-ag-tablespaces.html): "*The location must be an existing, empty directory that is owned by the PostgreSQL operating system user*" - is that directory owned by the `postgres` operating system user?

Comment: Simply remark: putting some non-static content below /var/www is imho not always so bad, if the permissions of the webserver are set up correctly. The problem what I see that it is set up in the rarest case correctly. Typically, the webserver run as a single user for all the websites, and many user can upload executable files into /var/www...

Answer (score 1):

`data_directory` is defined per cluster and so is same for all databases.
what you probably want instead is creating a tablespace in a different location and storing all data in one DB in that tablespace...